# How to remove a range of rows from a vb.net openxml IEnumerable(Of Row) object?

Tags: vb.net, openxml

I am using openxml in a vb.net project to parse the data in an Excel file with a large number of rows into a DataTables object. Each row in the excel file is parsed and added as a DataRow object in the DataTable.

If the job fails, I want to skip all of the rows that were already parsed.  However, I still need to parse the first row because it is used to setup the column names in the DataTable.

I am looking for a way to remove rows 2 through X in an openxml IEnumerable(Of Row) object.

```
    'open the excel doc
    Dim doc As SpreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(FilePath, False)

    'Read the first Sheet from Excel file.
    Dim sheet As Sheet = doc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets.GetFirstChild(Of Sheet)()

    'Get the Worksheet instance.
    Dim worksheet As Worksheet = TryCast(doc.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(sheet.Id.Value), WorksheetPart).Worksheet

    'Fetch all the rows present in the Worksheet. 
    Dim rows As IEnumerable(Of Row) = worksheet.GetFirstChild(Of SheetData)().Descendants(Of Row)()

    ' set a starting row value
    Dim startingRow as Integer = 125000

    'Remove rows 2 through startingRow from the "rows" IEnumerable(Of Row) variable..
    '** this is where I am stuck!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

FYI, C# is added as a tag since there are not that many active VB programmers out there any more. I will gladly convert any C# solutions/tips to VB.

Comment: There is no way to remove items from an `IEnumerable` because, by definition, an `IEnumerable` is an object that can be enumerated and that's all. With regards to interfaces, it is `IList` that allows random access and, therefore, addition, insertion and removal. All you can do is enumerate the object and ignore the items you don't want. You can create a new `IEnumerable` from the first and only include the items you want in various ways, including with `Where` or, if it's indexes that matter, with `Skip` and `Take`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather then "removing" rows from a read-only `IEnumerable`, a more straightforward way would to just iterate over the rows you *do* want, namely row 1, then rows X+1 to the end:

```
  rows = rows.Take(1).Concat(rows.Skip(startingRow))
```

Comment: Does exactly what I am asking for. Thank you!